# Gitlab 11.1.4 incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Tags: ruby, gitlab

Since the evening, after renewal of the SSL certificate of the subdomain related to Github and may be after an automatic update of Centos7 server and mariadb (while I'm sure it has nothing to do with it) my gitlab stopped working.

I tried reconfigure and restart several times, no chance.

Here is the exact error from the tail

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 196.229.241.110 at 2018-08-15 01:26:28 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8):
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:26:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml___4353105439635492698_70226876228260'
  app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__4146057416282651987_70226896429000'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:29:in `new'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:51:in `with_locale'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:57:in `with_user_locale'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:370:in `set_locale'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:97:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  ee/lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:38:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:10:in `call'

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

The config-check (gitlab-rake) returned that everything is fine .. I simply can't find anything related to this issue specially for gitlab versions above 10 (mine is 11.1.4, latest one)

Can anyone help ? I'm running this in a Centos7 Plesk server, over Nginx with SSL